# MultipartEntityBuilder.create cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

I try to create a multipartEntityBuilder in oder to send an httpRequest. The code i found was using MultipartEntity, so i changed that to MultipartEntityBuilder.
`MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = new MultipartEntityBuilder.create();`
This gives me an error

> MultipartEntityBuilder.create cannot be resolved to a type

I have added the httpmime-4.5.jar file in my eclipse /lib (from the properties menu) and i can actually see the create() method inside the MultipartEntityBuilder class.(I cant see the code, just that it exist there).
And of course i have imported it.
`import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;`

I have been looking around and the only answer i could find was to include the jar.
Any ideas?

Comment: it is getting really late! i cant believe i missed that. `new` was just sitting there from the time of `= new MultipartEntity` that was part of the background for me. wasnt even seeing it anymore! Thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to call a **method**, the expression on the right hand side of the assignment shouldn't start with `new`:

```
MultipartEntityBuilder reqEntity = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
```

Otherwise the compiler expects a constructor call, which would mean you'd call the default constructor of the `create` class that is a static inner class of `MultipartEntityBuilder`.